# How are Rikka's and Shichimiya's powers being affected?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

In the second season of "Love, Chunibyou and and other Delusions", Rikka's powers start weakening in the 9th episode. I don't get what's going on. Their powers are supposed to be imaginary. Then how is it possible for something imaginary to weaken unless the person imagines them to be weakening themselves. Rikka doesn't really have any reason to imagine that and apparently, from her reactions, she doesn't like it. Then what's causing it and why is it happening?

Furthermore, Shichimiya also tells Rikka about what once happened to her and that she decided to keep her powers and remain the magical devil girl. Does that mean that if she had fallen in love with Yuuta back then, her powers would have disappeared?

What do their powers have to do with Yuuta?

Comment: I tought that imaginary powers were like imaginary friends.
Once you got something more interesting and/or more important, the delusions started to become unecessary.

But for real answer, I guess we would need word of god.

Comment: Yeah but Rikka's chunibyou personality is really important to her. She didn't want to lose her powers. And she actually went through to strengthen them once more because she really needed them. I doubt if her chunibyou is any less important than love.

Comment: I think it was not really a conscious decision.
Rikka usedthe delusions to cope with life in mostly every aspect, but her feeling for Yuuta made her more confortable and satisfied with reality, she had less need for the delusions.
And yet, she needed the delusions, she was accostumed to them, so she didn't want to lose them.

I guess something similar happened to Shichimiya. Had she accepted her love back then, she might have let go of all the delusions and started a more conventional school life.

But again, that's only my view  on the anime.
Now I really want some word of god on this...

Comment: Love seems to be the only reason for it all. Both Shichimiya and Rikka were in similar situations when that happened. But I don't see how their imagination gets affected. I like your reasoning but I think I will wait till I get a more satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4):

Rikka's imaginary "powers" are a reflection of how she perceives herself. The events of the series had begun to make her question whether it was time for her to "grow up" and give up on chuuni games; this internal doubt "manifested" itself as "weakened" powers.

Comment: I like the explanation. The part about it being as a result of the feeling that she had to grow up kind of makes sense. But what do you think about Shichimiya? She was able to retain her powers or something like that about she got over Yuuta. Doesn't that hint like it has something to do with love?

Comment: That is a great point. Something to remember, though, is that their powers are 100% imaginary. Rikka and Shichimiya probably have slightly different ways of thinking about love, and this would probably be reflected in their "powers" (which they often make up/append on the fly).

Answer (score -1):

First let's go back to why they develop the "power" in the first place. Rikka developed her power after she witnessed Yuuta in action as Dark Flame Master from the balcony of her sister, Takanashi Touka's room. Why do she develop such power? Because she was lonely. She was very close to her father and her father's sudden death (because Touka and her mother didn't inform her beforehand as they thought she was too young) caused a great shock to her. She can't accept his death and thus, seeing Yuuta's power, she developed her own where her goal is to find the Unseen Horizon which she believe is the place where she can meet her father again.

She then fall in love with Yuuta, the one that she idolized. However, at that time Yuuta was no longer Dark Flame Master. Yuuta has accepted reality and is living in it despite his power coming back occasionally (and accidentally). Rikka realized that Yuuta wanted her to stop being a chuunibyou (happened in the 2nd season of the anime). This caused her to waver between the chuunibyou way of live and the real world and that manifest in her power growing weaker. **Her love for him caused her power to grow weaker since Yuuta expected her to be 'normal'**.

As for Shichimiya, I don't know why her power got weaker when she fell in love with Yuuta since it was only mentioned briefly in the anime and I don't read the light novel.

Comment: Yeah well your answer is partly right but I really don't think that Yuuta wanted Rikka to be normal anymore in the second season. He accepts her chuunibyou personality at the end of the first season and their "pact" is proof that Yuuta totally accepts her chuunibyou. It's obvious when confronted by Nibutani, Yuuta tells her that he likes Rikka the way she is. Rikka was the one of made the pact herself. There is no way Yuuta wanted her to be normal. And Rikka knew that too. If that was the case, Rikka would have stayed normal like in the first season.

Answer (score -1):

It would have been 100x better if she just showed signs of growing up and giving up that childish act she had going on, it’s really weird watching a 17-18 years-old act like some kind of edgy chunibyou. I understand if she was still in elementary or middle school or even a high school freshman but after that, it just seems like that person might have a mental disability of some sort because that isn’t normal.

I believe the whole reason she acts that way is mainly because she wants to cover up her feelings of what had happened to her family. By putting on this act of some edgy devil girl with “powers”, it would have been a happier ending if she threw it all aside and decided to give up that act and see life for what it really is.